# Up button in preference activity

Tags: android

I want to use the Up button into a `PreferenceActivity`, so i tried to use this code

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

But eclipse give me `"Call requires API level 11 (current min is 10): android.preference.PreferenceActivity#getActionBar"` How can i fix?

I tried also with

```
@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
private void process() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

But I've the same error.

```
@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.mylayout);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Same error.

Comment: I think' you did not get my example. Please try again with the new example.

Comment: Check my updated question with your example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
  getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

to

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
  // Use the Android API
}else{
 // Use the Support Library..
}
```

Check by the integers, because the constants are introduced in their appropriate versions

Comment: this is bad code style and should raise a "magic number" warning.

Comment: Here the Problem is using of **PreferenceActivity#getActionBar** , that was introduced in API 11 you cant use in below API 11, but no prob you are checking the Build Version and you are using...

Comment: **ActionBar** was introduced in API 11 http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html , and below versions you can use the support library

Answer (score 0):

Suppress this warning for the given method by annotating it with

```
@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
```

like this:

```
@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   // .. whatever
   if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
       getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
   }
   // .. whatever
}
```